# Using nginx as a reverse proxy and load balancer, is there a way to automatically detect new container instances when using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I have a docker-compose setup, where an nginx container is being used as a reverse-proxy and load balancer for the rest of the containers that make up my application.

I can spin up the application using `docker-compose up -d` and everything works great. Then, I can scale up one of my services using `docker-compose up -d --scale auth=3`, and everything continues to work fine.

The only issue is that nginx is not yet aware of the two new instances, so I need to manually restart the nginx process inside the running container using `docker exec revproxy nginx -s reload`, "revproxy" being the name of the nginx container.

That's fine and dandy, I don't mind running an extra command when I decide to scale out one of my services. The real issue though is when there is a container failure somewhere... nginx needs to know as soon as this happens to stop sending traffic to the failed instance until the Docker engine is able to replace it with a healthy one.

With all that said, essentially I would like to accomplish what they are doing in the [Traefik quickstart tutorial](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/ac6b11037dabd4dd64f75c486d6c68ef3c5e9eb9/docs/content/getting-started/quick-start.md), except I would like to stick with nginx as my reverse-proxy.

Comment: Are you aware of [nginx unit](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx-unit/)? I think it is possible to tell Docker to notify nginx unit so it automatically routes to the new container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I personally think Traefik would be a real time saver in your case, there is another project which does what you want with nginx: [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy).

It works by listening to docker engine events and when containers are added or removed, it updates a nginx config using a template.

You could either use this `jwilder/nginx-proxy` docker image at is is, or you can also make your own flavor by using the [jwilder/docker-gen](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen) project which is the part that produces a file given a template and docker engine events.

But again, I would recommend [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) ; for the time and trouble saved and for all the features that comes with it (different load balancing strategies, healthchecks, circuit breakers, automatic SSL certificate setup with ACME/Let's Encrypt, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write a service discovery script that looks for the updated list of containers every X interval and update the nginx config accordingly.